# How to download part of file from the url?

Tags: download

A huge file was located on the url .
http://gensho.acc.umu.se/debian-cd/8.2.0/amd64/iso-cd/debian-8.2.0-amd64-lxde-CD-1.iso

Now i want to download 10000 bytes between 10000th byte  and 19999th byte on the file .
HOW to write the php command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would read 8K of binary data from the URL:

```
$filename = "http://gensho.acc.umu.se/debian-cd/8.2.0/amd64/iso-cd/debian-8.2.0-amd64-lxde-CD-1.iso";
$handle = fopen($filename, "rb");
$contents = fread($handle, 8192);
fclose($handle);
```

see http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php

In order to read from the 10,000nd byte up to the 19,999th you need to skip the first 10,000 bytes, as there is no "filepointer" which can be positioned w/o reading like fseek on normal files:

```
...
$skip= fread($handle, 10000);
$contents = fread($handle, 9999);
...
```

Comment: download 10000 bytes between 10000th byte and 19999th byte on the file ,not just 8192 ,not btween the first byte and 8192th byte.

Comment: This can't be achieved as there is no "fseek" on streams. You need to read the 19999 bytes entirely and drop the first 10000 by the use of fread. see changed answer